# select unique names while removing the duplicates from a column

Tags: ensembl

I have a file with Ensembl gene and Transcript IDs :

> [image]

I want to retain only the first entires from both the column so that the output looks like this:

```
ENSG00000003137 ENST00000001146
ENSG00000003402 ENST00000309955
```

and ignore the rest. 
Have tried awk `awk '!a[$1$2]++'` and versions of it. Nothing works.
Kindly suggest some way to get the desired output.

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
awk '!a[$1]++' file.txt
```

If you have a different command line separator you need to specify with the `-F` option.

Space

```
awk -F' ' '!a[$1]++' text.txt
```

Tab

```
awk -F'\t' '!a[$1]++' text.txt
```

If you don't have the first column in order maybe should be a good idea sort first.

```
sort text.txt | awk -F' ' '!a[$1]++'
```

The name of the array in this case is `a`. There is a better explanation in [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1107659).

Answer (score 1):

That sound like a job for a perl one-liner:

```
perl -ane 'unless(exists $seen{$F[0]}){print $_; $seen{$F[0]}++}'
```

Explanation:
 
The input is read line-wise and printed back to the command line if the ID in the first column has not been seen before.

- `perl -ane '` reads input line-wise and splits fields to array @F
- `unless(exists $seen{$F[0]}){` checks if ID exists in hash %seen and continues if that is not the case
- `print $_;` prints the original input to STDOUT
- `$seen{$F[0]}++}'` adds the ID to the hash %seen